# queues server for xml messages

Tags: java, xml, message-queue, database-migration, data-migration

My question is quite general.

I have data migration between two systems, both written in Java, one oracle database, one db2. I would like to organise migration indirectly via queues messages server with xml messages. In order to assure ex. possibility to send messages to the queue even when receiving system is off etc. and to have fully transactional approach.

What technologies could you recommend and why?

Comment: Generally, "recommend tools" is an opinion question and offtopic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can meet the requirement for async transfer using file transfer or using temporary tables in one of the databases. And that will provide you transactions. I have used both the approaches in my previous projects and these can handle incremental transfer and large volumes of data (~ 20GB at a time).

Migrating data using XML messages is possible in theory, and will work for small volumes of data (<20MB) .You will soon face memory, network and performance issues if the volume of data increases.

You can use JMS for messaging. Some application servers provides JMS infrastructure. Websphere application server provides transaction and reliability of JMS messages. Or you can use some other Messaging product like WebSphere MQ.

Comment: I know xml messages have weak points, but it's quite easy to check different things even if one database or even both are off. Thus I would prefer to use queues, but don't know what solution.